# Regex match specific tags and any characters in between

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I am trying to use regex to match specific tags and any characters/content between specific tags. Note that the content between the tags is dynamic so can change.

I want to match everything between ***[vc_row el_class="hero-cta*** and ***[/vc_row]***

I attempted this with the following regex but the problem is it matches all ***[vc_row]*** tags, where as I want to be able to only match ***[vc_row el_class="hero-cta*** tags, the inside content, and the closing ***[/vc_row]*** tag

**My attempted regex** (incorrect as it matches all [vc_row] tags)

```
\[vc_row el_class=[^\]].*\"\]([\s\S]*)\[\/vc_row\]
```

How can I adapt this regex?

**Content**

```
<!--match-->
[vc_row el_class="hero-cta image_flush_bottom" css=".vc_custom_1382221210419{background-color: #511068c !important;}"][vc_column][vc_row_inner el_class="container-row-margin-btm-override"][vc_column_inner width="2/3"][vc_column_text]
 <h2><em><strong>Download Guide</strong></em></h2>
[/vc_column_text][/vc_column_inner][vc_column_inner width="1/3"][vc_single_image image="12346" img_size="full" alignment="center" onclick="custom_link" link="https://www.website.com/test-page"] 
   [/vc_column_inner][/vc_row_inner][/vc_column][/vc_row]
<!--//match-->

<!--ignore-->
[vc_row][vc_column][breadcrumb][/vc_column][/vc_row]
<!--//ignore-->
```

Comment: `\[vc_row el_class=[^]]+].*?\[/vc_row]` with `s` (dotall) modifer

Comment: @ctwheels thanks but that did not work and did not find a match. See : https://www.regextester.com/index.php?fam=112604

Comment: That's because you didn't use PCRE regex (as you specified in your question) and enabled the dotall/dot matches newline modifier. See it working [here](https://regex101.com/r/5XRRAf/1)

Comment: @ctwheels I changed it to PCRE and still no match? Also what do you mean enable the dotall modifier?

Comment: I added a link to my last comment, you can see it working.

Comment: @ctwheels thanks. Is there a way to do it without the ~ delimiter? I am using WP-CLI regex.

Comment: It's just using those as delimiters so that I don't have to escape the `/` in the regex pattern.

Comment: @ctwheels perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In WordPress have function `get_shortcode_regex` for finding all shortcodes.

```
echo get_shortcode_regex( [ 'vc_row' ] );
```

This regular can help you find all vc_row shortcodes. You can reformat this regular for your purpose.